# Non-linear curve fitting fail to converge

Tags: nonlinear-regression, convergence

I'm using the curve fitting toolbox to fit 31 data points to a function: y = a*(1-b*exp(-c*x)-(1-b)*exp(-d*x)). (Algorithm: Trust region. The boundaries set for the parameters are: a: 0.25 - Inf, b: 0-1, c: 0-Inf, d: 0-Inf)

For a certain group of data, the fitting fails to converge.
[image]

For some groups of data, the fitting can converge but the standard error of the fitted parameters are very big.
[image]

I have a feeling that this is because my function is overparameterised, but I can't prove. The equation used here comes from a model in the bioenergy field that is believed can be used to describe the anaerobic biogas production. So if I can prove that this equation is overparameterised mathematically than just a hunch, the result can be more convincing.

Comment: It is not over-parameterized.  It's just that exponential curves even with fairly large differences between their rates $c$ and $d$ can be practically interchangeable and when one of the rates is small, they are hard to distinguish from a constant.  This is an extremely difficult function to fit unless you have a large number of points, extremely small errors, or huge range of $x$ values.  To learn more, examine the covariance matrix of the parameter estimates: in particular, study its eigenvalues and look at the parameter combination associated with the smallest eigenvalue(s).

Comment: In looking closely at the image, I see some other problems.  For instance, you seem to include points (0,0) in your data.  This is incorrect, because the zero gas usage is not observed and it has no error.  For a better representation of the precision of the estimates, you should omit such assumed values.  There is also evidence of strong positive serial correlation. This, too, will lead to overly optimistic (that is, too-narrow) confidence intervals.  The first fit is pretty good, so one resolution is to continue the iterations until convergence does occur.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For the first example which failed to converge, I fit it using the syntax "nlinfit" in Matlab again instead of using the curve fitting toolbox, it gave such warning "Some columns of the Jacobian are effectively zero at the solution, indicating that the model is insensitive to some of its parameters.  That may be because those parameters are not present in the model, or otherwise do not affect the predicted values.  It may also be due to numerical underflow in the model function."

Comment: The covariance matrix for 4 parameters is [ 0.0023 , -0.0000 ,-0.0003 ,-0.0030; -0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000; -0.0003, 0.0000, 0.0001, 0.0005; -0.0030, 0.0000, 0.0005, 0.0048]. The principal component coefficients matrix is   
 [-0.5508, 0.8346, -0.0000, 0.0000;  0.0000, -0.0000, -0.4108, 0.9117; 0.0922, 0.0608, 0.9061, 0.4083; 0.8295, 0.5475, -0.1007, -0.0454]. The eigenvalues are  0.0069, 0.0003, 0.0000, 0.0000 respectively.

Comment: Lastly, when fitting this function to one particular sample multiple times, I found the fitted values for parameter a are almost the same every time, but parameter b can have two or three solutions.

Comment: When you are having numerical problems, it won't do to report the covariance matrix to just one or two significant figures.  You, yourself, will need to analyze this matrix in full (double) precision as produced by your software.  The problem ultimately is that this is either a poor model for your data or you haven't observed any $x$ values large enough to distinguish both exponentials from a constant.